# Vuejs same function on multiple divs need to run seperately

Tags: vue.js

Alright, I have these two divs with a mouseover and they have the same function. Now the problem is that if I mouse over one of them then BOTH shines. How to solve this? So shines one by one when I hover them.

DIVS:

```
 <div class="latestItemBody" @mouseover="shineItemIcon"
@mouseout="shineOff" :style="{background: activeCardBg}">

<div class="latestItemBody" @mouseover="shineItemIcon"
@mouseout="shineOff" :style="{background: activeCardBg}">
```

Functions:

```
methods: {
    shineItemIcon() {
        this.activeCardBg = '#7a00ff';
        this.bounce = 'animated bounceIn';
    },
    shineOff() {
        this.activeCardBg = '';
        this.bounce = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why they both "shine" is because you have `activeCardBg` bound to both of them, which changes the background.

You could add the shine effect with pure CSS like this instead.

```
// CSS
.latestItemBody:hover {
    background-color: #7a00ff
}
```

If you want to do this with JS, it could be done like this.

```
 // Template
 <div 
   class="latestItemBody" 
   @mouseover="shineItemIcon"
   @mouseout="shineOff">
 </div>

 <div 
   class="latestItemBody" 
   @mouseover="shineItemIcon"
   @mouseout="shineOff">
 </div>

 // Methods
 shineItemIcon(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#7a00ff';
    this.bounce = 'animated bounceIn';
 },
 shineOff(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
    this.bounce = '';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the div id as parameter to the shineitemicon and shineoff function. depending upon the condition set 'activeCardBg' value. give activecardBg1 to first div and activeCardBg2 to second div.